# Decoding Firebase DB Snapshot with Struct in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I decode a DB request from my Firebase realtime database in Swift? The following is returning nil

```
struct PromoCode: Codable {
    var amount: Int
    var code: String
}

func getPromoCodes(handler: @escaping ([PromoCode]?) -> ()) {
        promoCodes.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
            print("SNAPSHOT: \(snapshot.value)")
            guard let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: snapshot.value as Any, options: []) else { return }
            let codes = try? JSONDecoder().decode([PromoCode].self, from: data)
            handler(codes)
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Don´t use `try?`. Use `try` and wrap it in a do/catch block or use `try!` to get the error and add it to your question.

Comment: It would be helpful for us to know what `promoCodes` resolves to as it could be pointing to an invalid node. Likewise, `.value` reads in all child data and if that doesn't match your structure, it may also fail. Please update the question with more details and see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)